# random sampling of imbalance class

Tags: machine-learning, classification

I have a large Data Set that contain around 9,00,000 records.
My Target Variable contain Boolean value as 0 and 1.

```
1 = Affected record
0 = Normal records
```

The issue is my full data set contain only 1904 record as affected accounts.

What is the best way for random sampling (Taking at least 100000 record for training the model) to avoid Bias and over fitting of my model towards the majority class.

Will SMOTE be a good option?

Comment: Too broad a question for SO; class imbalance is a *huge* sub-topic in itself, with several techniques to handle it. I kindly suggest you start googling...

Comment: If you have a low amount of positive data you could go with anomaly detection model which is meant for skewed cases like this.

Answer (score 0):

You could use an anomaly detection model. First, train the amount of dataset you want(say 0.1 Mn) and calculate the mean and variance of the data. You could then use the validation set(labelled data) to find some threshold value. Then you could decide whether a sample is an anomaly or not by seeing the probability of that value.

p(x) < epsilon(threshold) ---> anomaly
p(x) > epsilon(threshold) ---> not anomaly